# Как исправить ошибку при передачи id из одного массива в другой?

Tags: php, битрикс

При передаче id пользователей `$rsUsers["ID"]` из одного массива в методе получения свойств пользователям в id другого массива `$res = CUser::GetUserGroupList($rsUsers["ID"])` метода получения групп и даты активности пользователя в них. 
возникает следующая ошибка:

**Fatal error: Cannot use object of type CDBResult as array in /var/www/vhosts/suoly.evr.com/httpdocs/sup/test1/index.php on line 39**

Вот код который выполняется:

```html
<?
global $USER;
$arfilter = Array(
            "ID" => $_REQUEST['MANAGER_ID'].' | '.$_REQUEST['USES_ID'],
   "UF_TO_KVALIF"=> "1"
        );
        $arParameters = array(
            'SELECT' => array("UF_*")
        );
$rsUsers = CUser::GetList(($by="id"), ($order="asc"), $arfilter, $arParameters);
$is_filtered = $rsUsers->is_filtered; // отфильтрована ли выборка ?
$rsUsers->NavStart(50); // разбиваем постранично по 50 записей
echo $rsUsers->NavPrint(GetMessage("PAGES")); // печатаем постраничную навигацию
while($rsUsers->NavNext(true, "f_")) :
    echo "[".$f_ID."] (".$f_LOGIN.") ".$f_NAME." ".$f_LAST_NAME."<br>"; 
endwhile;
$res = CUser::GetUserGroupList($rsUsers["ID"]);
while ($arGroup = $res->Fetch()){
   print "<pre>"; print_r($arGroup); print "</pre>";
}

var_dump($rsUsers);
?>
```

```
string(19) "09.01.2018 11:13:57" object(CDBResult)#74 (36) { ["result"]=> resource(12) of type (mysql result) ["arResult"]=> array(7) { [0]=> array(112) { ["ID"]=> string(2) "40" ["TIMESTAMP_X"]=> string(19) "26.12.2017 10:26:47" ["LOGIN"]=> string(16) "Timur.Khamidulin" ["PASSWORD"]=> string(40) "A9(ty.2Lbe3e1b76a1c4be325c0af545e8793d0a" ["CHECKWORD"]=> string(40) "Apm5zht8274def2481d7669a8be64d6edeb09bb8" ["ACTIVE"]=> string(1) "Y" ["NAME"]=> string(0) "" ["LAST_NAME"]=> string(0) "" ["EMAIL"]=> string(26) "Timur.Khamidulin@evraz.com" ["LAST_LOGIN"]=> string(19) "11.07.2017 10:50:36" ["DATE_REGISTER"]=> string(19) "12.10.2016 12:13:39" ["LID"]=> string(2) "s1" ["PERSONAL_PROFESSION"]=> string(0) "" ["PERSONAL_WWW"]=> string(0) "" ["PERSONAL_ICQ"]=> string(0) "" ["PERSONAL_GENDER"]=> string(0) "" ["PERSONAL_BIRTHDATE"]=> NULL ["PERSONAL_PHOTO"]=> NULL ["PERSONAL_PHONE"]=> string(0) "" ["PERSONAL_FAX"]=> string(0) "" ["PERSONAL_MOBILE"]=> string(0) "" ["PERSONAL_PAGER"]=> string(0) "" ["PERSONAL_STREET"]=> string(0) "" ["PERSONAL_MAILBOX"]=> string(0) "" ["PERSONAL_CITY"]=> string(0) "" ["PERSONAL_STATE"]=> string(0) "" ["PERSONAL_ZIP"]=> string(0) "" ["PERSONAL_COUNTRY"]=> string(1) "0" ["PERSONAL_NOTES"]=> string(0) "" ["WORK_COMPANY"]=> string(0) "" ["WORK_DEPARTMENT"]=> string(0) "" ["WORK_POSITION"]=> string(0) "" ["WORK_WWW"]=> string(0) "" ["WORK_PHONE"]=> string(0) "" ["WORK_FAX"]=> string(0) "" ["WORK_PAGER"]=> string(0) "" ["WORK_STREET"]=> string(0) "" ["WORK_MAILBOX"]=> string(0) "" ["WORK_CITY"]=> string(0) "" ["WORK_STATE"]=> string(0) "" ["WORK_ZIP"]=> string(0) "" ["WORK_COUNTRY"]=> string(1) "0" ["WORK_PROFILE"]=> string(0) "" ["WORK_LOGO"]=> NULL ["WORK_NOTES"]=> string(0) "" ["ADMIN_NOTES"]=> string(0) "" ["STORED_HASH"]=> NULL ["XML_ID"]=> string(0) "" ["PERSONAL_BIRTHDAY"]=> NULL ["EXTERNAL_AUTH_ID"]=> NULL ["CHECKWORD_TIME"]=> string(19) "2017-12-26 10:26:47" ["SECOND_NAME"]=> string(0) "" ["CONFIRM_CODE"]=> NULL ["LOGIN_ATTEMPTS"]=> string(1) "0" ["LAST_ACTIVITY_DATE"]=> NULL ["AUTO_TIME_ZONE"]=> string(0) "" ["TIME_ZONE"]=> NULL ["TIME_ZONE_OFFSET"]=> NULL ["TITLE"]=> string(0) "" ["BX_USER_ID"]=> string(32) "2d2dbbaaf8fd36cfa24708676e9f7929" ["LANGUAGE_ID"]=> string(0) "" ["IS_ONLINE"]=> string(1) "N" ["UF_PROJ_SERVICES"]=> string(1) "1" ["UF_PROJ_ILLIQUIDS"]=> string(1) "1" ["UF_PROJ_ILLQ_TEND"]=> string(1) "0" ["UF_ISJUR"]=> NULL ["UF_NAME"]=> string(10) "Тимур" ["UF_MIDNAME"]=> string(16) "Фаизович" ["UF_SURNAME"]=> string(18) "Хамидулин" ["UF_SKILL1"]=> string(1) "1" ["UF_SKILL2"]=> string(1) "1" ["UF_CONC_ILLIQ_SKILL"]=> string(1) "1" ["UF_TO_KVALIF"]=> string(1) "1" ["UF_TEMPLATE_MAIL_NOT"]=> NULL ["UF_TEMPLATE_MAIL_YES"]=> NULL ["UF_GRUPP_LIENT_DATA_"]=> string(0) "" ["UF_FULLNAME"]=> NULL ["UF_SHORTNAME"]=> NULL ["UF_JUR_ADRESS"]=> NULL ["UF_FACT_ADRESS"]=> NULL ["UF_POST_ADRESS"]=> string(1) "2" ["UF_PASPARTY"]=> string(27) "сер. 1111 ном. 111111" ["UF_MOBILE"]=> string(10) "2111111111" ["UF_REGISTRATION_DATE"]=> string(10) "11.11.2016" ["UF_REGISTRATION_PLAC"]=> string(1) "2" ["UF_REGISTRATION_ORG"]=> string(1) "1" ["UF_INN"]=> string(12) "111111111111" ["UF_OGRN"]=> string(15) "11111-11111-111" ["UF_ACTIVITY"]=> NULL ["UF_EXPERIENCE"]=> NULL ["UF_RELATIONS"]=> NULL ["UF_EQUIPMENT"]=> NULL ["UF_EQUIPMET_BASE"]=> NULL ["UF_SPEC_TECH"]=> NULL ["UF_AGREEMENT"]=> string(1) "1" ["UF_GENDIR"]=> NULL ["UF_GENDIR_MOB"]=> NULL ["UF_DIRECTOR"]=> NULL ["UF_DIRECTOR_MOB"]=> NULL
```

Comment: Посмотрите что выводит var_dump( $rsUsers ) - правильно ли ваше обращение к полю "ID". Скорее всего Вам надо обрщаться к нему так $rsUsers->ID

Comment: @sv458 Показывает NULL  и я правда, не пойму, почему я не могу просто обратиться к элементу массива таким образом, как у меня в коде. Попробую ваш вариант.

Comment: если var_dump($rsUsers) == NULL, то надо смотреть почему null. Естественно потом ничего работать не будет

Comment: @sv458  $rsUsers - не пустой массив,  в нем есть все нужные поля. Я имел ввиду var_dump($rsUsers['ID']); - показывает **Fatal error: Cannot use object of type CDBResult**... это то и странно

Comment: Добавте в вопрос вывод var_dump( $rsUsers )

Comment: Все дело в том, что в `$rsUsers` не массив, а объект класса `CDBResult`, внимательнее смотрите документации к фунцкиям которые используете. Вам нужно записать айдишники юзеров в массив и элементы этого массива поочереди скармливать в `CUser::GetUserGroupList`, потому что на вход эта функция принимает только целые числа, а не массивы.

Comment: @sv458 добавил вывод var_dump( $rsUsers )